# Try to adjust cdk-drop-list-receiving class to a whole list when dragging but without sorting the original list

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop

I'm using the drag and drop module of angular, and I'm trying to put the div container that has the cdk-drop-list-receiving class to the whole list of draggable items which is done with a ngfor.

I'm trying to drag one item from a list to another, but if the user wants to get the draggable item back to its original position before he or she drops it in the other container, I want to get the draggable item to its original position of the source list. Unfortunately, the area to get back the draggable item to the list stays at the first position of the list, doesn't encompass the area of the whole list, so I could drop the item at any position of the list, but without reordering them.

The parent container has the cdkdroplist tag, which activates the cdk-drop-list-receiving class, and inside it I make the draggable cards with a ngfor, but the area to receive the draggable item its placed at the first position of the list always, no matter how many items are in the list. I'm asking if anyone comes with an idea of how I can fix this.

here is an image of the areas which are droppable:
[image]

the yellow area is the drop area, which is always at the top position of the list, even if the list has more height. I want to make the drop area to take the whole height of the list, but when I put back the draggable item, it cannot reorder the list, it has to be placed to its original position.

I've tried to put the cdkdroplist tag to each of the draggable cards made by the ngfor, but doing this doesn't appear the drop area.